# Calling two Bean methods in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to call two methods from the Bean to a JSF page within one primefaces component? I have `listOfNames()` and `detailsOfName()` methods in the Bean. The two methods return `List` types.

In a `<p:dataGrid>`, is it possible to obtain the values from both the methods?

Comment: I fail to udnerstand your question. "In a" what? "To a JSF page" - what calls whose methods?

Comment: @Dariusz: Click *edit* to see it. The OP neglected to pay attention and love to formatting rules and question preview. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't invoke multiple properties. Just merge the both lists into one list and return it instead.

E.g.

```
List<String> listOfEverything = new ArrayList<String>();
listOfEverything.addAll(listOfNames);
listOfEverything.addAll(detailsOfName);
```

Keep in mind that [you should not be doing business job in getter methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062). Do the preparing job in bean's (post)constructor or (action)listener method depending on whether you need this on a GET or POST request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

(I'll take care to better phrase my question. Thanks once again!)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the way BalusC proposed, but would also introduce the ability to separate the two lists back, if needed, in your view, or elsewhere, thus returning either `List<List<String>>`, or `Map<String, List<String>>`, which is

```
    List<List<String>> unitedList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    unitedList.add(listOfNames);
    unitedList.add(detailsOfName);
```

or

```
    Map<String, List<String>> unitedMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    unitedMap.put("listOfNames", listOfNames);
    unitedList.add("detailsOfName", detailsOfName);
```

Comment: He want to show it in a single `<p:dataGrid>`. Admittedly, there may be more elegant ways, the `DetailsOfName` could perhaps better be a property of `Name`, but ala, the OP asked so and the point is after all that you've to prepare beforehand so that a single result can be returned :)

Comment: I think that it is a problem (and an example) of ill design. His bean should contain list of objects with `.name` and `.detail` fields.